# Making/editing patterns in 2D array. (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to make a tile based game. On top of the block tiles, there are transparent shade tiles. Each shade tile will have a different transparency value based on the light sources nearby. What I'm having trouble with is the painstaking work required to set a pattern of a 2D array (equal to a circular selection of tiles in the game) each change their values slightly.
Right now I have a shade class, which is the whole information for the shading of the current level. This class has a 2D array equal to the tiles:

```
[[1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,],
[1,1,1,1,1,],
[1,1,1,1,1,],
[1,1,1,1,1,]]
```

This code here is a block that edits the area around a torch, x and y being the x and y values of the torch on the map. I would like to know if this code can be shortened so that a circular area can be made lighter? Also, if a variable radius was presented, is there an easy way for the tiles in that radius to be edited by that pattern/algorithm?

```
shade.map[x][y] = 0
shade.map[x-1][y] = 64
shade.map[x-2][y] = 128
shade.map[x+1][y] = 64
shade.map[x+2][y] = 128
shade.map[x][y+1] = 64
shade.map[x][y+2] = 128
shade.map[x][y-1] = 64
shade.map[x][y-2] = 128
shade.map[x-1][y-1] = 96
shade.map[x+1][y-1] = 96
shade.map[x+1][y+1] = 96
shade.map[x-1][y+1] = 96
```

Comment: For loops? That's what I would use.

Comment: Or simple function that returns a list of indexes but then u might as well just write a function for the whole thing

Comment: Perhaps evidence of the painstaking tedium of it - did you also want to include `shade.map[x][y-1]` and `shape.map[x][y-2]`?

Comment: Wow, I actually forgot that. My point exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some have mentioned, for loops might serve you well here. I'm not exactly sure what your radius function ought to look like, as you seem to have:

```
?   ?  128 ?  ?
?   48 64  48 ?
128 64 0   64 128
?   48 64  48 ?
?   ?  128 ?  ?
```

Do you have two different ideas for how you would like to radiate this outward, one for straight lines, and one for diagonals (sorry if I'm missing some clear/obvious math progression).

Let's at least start with the direct left-right-up-down, and maybe I can address the diagonal with more info later.

```
def update(shade, x, y, radius=2):
    increases = [i*64 for i in range(radius+1)] # [0, 64, 128] for example
    for i in range(radius+1):
        shade.map[x+i][y] = increases[i]
        shade.map[x-i][y] = increases[i]
        shade.map[x][y+i] = increases[i]
        shade.map[x][y-i] = increases[i]
```

This should radiate outwards and do almost what you want (only in straight lines), except for when you fall off the end of the array: if you tried this, and gave `x, y = 4, 2`, for example, you'd start to get `IndexError`s. So, now we want to make this wrap around the end of a row and back to the beginning:

```
128 ?  ?   ?   ?
64  48 ?   ?   48
0   64 128 128 64
64  48 ?   ?   48
128 ?  ?   ?   ?
```

Which might look like it would be much harder to implement in code, but luckily, it's not:

```
def update(shade, x, y, radius=2):
    mlen = len(shade.map)  ## assuming it's a square array; use xlen and ylen separately if needed
    increases = [i*64 for i in range(radius+1)] # [0, 64, 128] for example
    for i in range(radius+1):
        shade.map[(x+i)%mlen][y] = increases[i]
        shade.map[(x-i)%mlen][y] = increases[i]
        shade.map[x][(y+i)%mlen] = increases[i]
        shade.map[x][(y-i)%mlen] = increases[i]
```

All we had to do was determine our updating indices modulo the length (and technically, this wasn't necessary for the negative movements, since it can index from the end of a list just as you might expect. For code consistency, I might do the above, for code efficiency, I would leave the modulo out, and would also use `for i in range(1, radius+1)` since `i = 0` doesn't change anything).

**Edit**
Figured I should add something about diagonal, though the above may have been enough to bootstrap the idea.

```
def update_diagonal(shade, x, y, radius=1):
    mlen = len(shade.map)  ## assuming it's a square array; use xlen and ylen separately if needed
    increases = [i*48 for i in range(radius+1)] # [0, 48] for example
    for i in range(radius+1):
        shade.map[(x+i)%mlen][(y+i)%mlen] = increases[i]
        shade.map[(x+i)%mlen][(y-i)%mlen] = increases[i]
        shade.map[(x-i)%mlen][(y+i)%mlen] = increases[i]
        shade.map[(x-i)%mlen][(y-i)%mlen] = increases[i]
```

You could (and should?) merge these two functions into one if they are always going to be called together - define two different `increases` lists, and then just reference the appropriate one inside that single `for` loop.

Lastly, as a non-sequitur: python has a function called `map`, so I would stray away from using attributes or anything with that (or any other keyword). It probably wouldn't matter in this case, but is a better practice (similarly: try not to name variables `dict`, `list`, `file`, etc.).

Comment: Ah ok, didn't want to assume anything. That will be covered correctly by the radius value, then (in that, they won't get altered at all).

Comment: Is there any way to get the shade to not wraparound and also prevent index errors? I know it could be done with lots of if statements but is there an easier way?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. You'd need at least 4 if's, for the x, and the y, positive, or negative. I guess you could try using `min` and `max`, but at least at first glance, that's messier.